# C# Xamarin ; Private key - store and retrieve

Tags: xamarin, private-key, x509certificate2

I have an issue with retrieving Private key from `X509Storage` after restart of application.

I am working with:

- [Storage](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store/)
- [Certificate](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate/)

My process:

**1 Create storage**

```
Storage = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher, 
StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
Storage.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
```

**2 Create Certificate with Private key**

```
Cert = new X509Certificate2(
    Convert.FromBase64String("...my certificate..."),
    "",
    X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet | 
    X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |
    X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var privateKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
privateKey.FromXmlString("...my private key relevant to certificate...");
privateKey.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
Cert.PrivateKey = privateKey;
```

**3 Insert Certificate to storage**

```
Storage.Add(Cert);
```

**4 Verify, that Certificate with Private key is in storage**

```
var certs = Storage.Certificates;
foreach (var cert in certs)
{
   CertsView.Append("Name: " + cert.Subject + "; Has PK: "+ cert.HasPrivateKey +  "\n");
}
```

**5 Restart application and verify again**

I am able to retrieve certificate, which I have inserted.
However, certificate is without private key at this point.

What I am missing?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm kinda in the same spot...